# Date time elapse change string of names when changing to ex hour to hours

Tags: php, datetime

I've got this code snippet as you can see my language is a bit different then just adding the 'S the part where `Guess it's something here?` is where the **s** did go when i found this snippet, so what would be a good approach I've got stuck on ides at this moment.

```
    $string = array(
    'y' => 'år',
    'm' => 'månad',  // månader
    'w' => 'vecka',  // veckor
    'd' => 'dag',    // dagar
    'h' => 'timme',  // timmar
    'i' => 'minut',  // minuter
    's' => 'sekund', // sekunder
);
foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 'Guess it's somthing here ?' : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}
```

FULL CODE HERE

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $level = 7) {

$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
$diff = $now->diff($ago);

$diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
$diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

$string = array(
    'y' => 'år',
    'm' => 'månader',
    'w' => 'veckor',
    'd' => 'dagar',
    'h' => 'timme',
    'i' => 'minuter',
    's' => 'sekunder',
);
foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}

$string = array_slice($string, 0, $level);
return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
```

}

Comment: @prakashtank this was just for explanation see FULL CODE ... He just put 'Guess it's somthing here ?' for asking ....

Comment: by adding a second string with the bent form could that work as an approach ? 

my output as this moment is : `1 vecka, 22 timmetimmar, 4 minutminuter,` using string 2 `($diff->$k > 1 ? $string2[$k] : '')`

Comment: Your function is working fine `time_elapsed_string('2017-03-07')` will output `1 dagar, 12 timmes, 24 minuters, 17 sekunders ago`. Isn't this enough ?

Comment: Yeah got it to work now but the bending is wrong in my language 1 dagar should be 1 dag and if greater then 1 adding the bendings but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to work also did improve it to use future date. Here is the code if anyone feel the need for it if you're going to use it on a non english site with alot of bendings in it.

instead of full date you can change to time_elapsed_string(date,2) = year month.

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $level = 7) {
$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
$diff = $now->diff($ago);

$diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
$diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

$string = array(
    'y' => 'år',           // year
    'm' => 'månad',        // month
    'w' => 'vecka',        // week
    'd' => 'dag',          // day
    'h' => 'timme',        // hour
    'i' => 'minut',        // minute
    's' => 'sekund',       // second
);
$string2 = array(
    'y' => 'år',           // year
    'm' => 'månader',      // months
    'w' => 'veckor',       // weeks
    'd' => 'dagar',        // days
    'h' => 'timmar',       // hours
    'i' => 'minuter',      // minutes
    's' => 'sekunder',     // seconds
);

foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' .  ($v =$diff->$k > 1 ? $string2[$k] : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}
// ago, to, just now
string = array_slice($string, 0, $level);
return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ($diff->invert ? ' sen' : ' tills') : ' precis nu';
```

}